# why onCallStateChanged() on Android is invoked more than one time in a single call？

Tags: android

I wanted to implement an app that prevents calls like a firewall. When I debug my app, I found that when there is a call in, the **onCallStateChanged()** function in interface **PhoneStateListener** is invoked three times. As a result, preventing one call can result in three logs. I'm so confused!!

my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING && 
                PhoneUtil.getITelephony(tpm).isRinging()) {
                String flag = isBlockCall(myContext, myHelper, myTypes, incomingNumber);
                if (flag.length() > 0) {
                    blockCall();
                    myHelper.insertLog(new String[] { flag, incomingNumber, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), null });
                    showNotification(myContext, incomingNumber, System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Did you get your solution if you find please help me i am in same problem onCallStateChanged calls more than onces for IDLE

Comment: @Dharmendra I think the reason for this problem is the phone is so slow. When I used Moto Milestone to test, the problem was gone.

Comment: is it possible? i want an event for Call end is it possible?

Comment: @Dharmendra, i do not know about ending call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PinkyJie,

onCallStateChanged() is working with BroadcastReceiver. so onCallStateChanged() will always get called whenever call state get changed. There are three call states.

TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: Phone is in idle mode, no call action.
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: At least one call is active in any kind.
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting.
TelephonyManager.

system will never go beyond that. please refer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

```
public class TestPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

  public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa----------------------------------"+state);
    try {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING ) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this，but what I confused is that when a call in, this function is invoked with a input parameter **state=1**, in this function I invoked **endCall()** , then the **onCallStateChanged()** was invoked again, this time parameter state should be 0, cause it's CALL_STATE_IDLE now, but in my debugging, it was still 1.

Comment: i done small changes in your code see above and it works fine..see logcat output  04-07 11:41:07.149: INFO/System.out(3213): aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa------------------------------------------------1                          
04-07 11:41:25.684: INFO/System.out(3213): aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa--------------------------------------------------------0 . when my phone is ringing the state is 1 and after that it's 0. hope this will help you

Answer (score 11):

Answer lies in your code where you are creating a `TelephonyManager` and then Registering a listener with it. It would be getting registered for a listener every time you start a new call and therefore multiple listeners attached to same telephony Manager resulting in a onCallStateChanged() for every Listener.
try creating new Telephony Manager and registering it where it executes only for once.(Constructor).

> TelephonyManager tmanager=(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>
> tmanager.listen(new CallListener(),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

Comment: This comment is the right answer for the question why the listener is invoked "Multiple times".

Answer (score 9):

Just to better phrase Aakash's answer, `onCallStateChanged()` gets called multiple times because `TelephonyManager.listen()` is inside `onReceive()`. That way, a new `PhoneStateListener` is instantiated and registered to the `TelephonyManager` whenever an event is broadcast, so there's many of them.

I personally did something like this in my code:

```
if (noCallListenerYet) { // noCallListenerYet is static boolean
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(new OutgoingCallListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    noCallListenerYet = false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Okay now, I had been suffering from the same thing, but somehow I've found a way to do it.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallActionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static ThePhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) arg0
                .getSystemService(arg0.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (phoneStateListener == null) {
            phoneStateListener = new ThePhoneStateListener(arg0);
            manager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }

}
```

In this way the TelephonyManager will listen just once. Cheers . . .

Answer (score 0):

According to **[official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String))**

> Callback invoked when device call state changes.

- This means that whenever incoming call rings your phone, this will
  change the state.
- Incoming call is rejected, this will invoke a state change as well
- Incoming call is picked up, state changes !
- Finally no action, will also cause a state change

That is said, once a state is changed, it makes sense to be seen as fired twice upon any resulting reaction.

Comment: Is there a way to identify the reason for the call to end (rejection by current user, vs other side ended the call ) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes. It can be found under this API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#LISTEN_CALL_DISCONNECT_CAUSES

Comment: @androiddeveloper detailed docs can be found here:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/DisconnectCause

Comment: Thank you. Does it also have the associated phone number? It's weird that many callbacks don't have it. ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED has it, but I wonder if it is called before what you've shown.