# Android: Music Player gets started itself after sometime

Tags: android, service, media-player

In my app, I am using media player in service for playing a music file. It is working but eventually gets started itself after sometime, and music starts playing. I am not getting where is the problem. Below, I am posting my code:

**Media Player Service**

```
public class ChalisaService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener
{
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
static int playerFlag = 0;
TelephonyManager tm;
ActivityManager actManager;
/**
 * 0 for stop/pause
 * 1 for play*/
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}//onBind

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.chalisa);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}//onCreate

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        /*HanuAlarm.txtPlay.setText("Play");
        HanuAlarm.btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnplay);*/
        playerFlag = 0;
    }//if
    else
    {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        /*HanuAlarm.txtPlay.setText("Pause");
        HanuAlarm.btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnpause);*/
        playerFlag = 1;
    }//else

    startForeground(0, null);
    return playerFlag;
}//onStartCommand

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    /*//mediaPlayer.stop();
    //mediaPlayer.release();
    playerFlag = 0;
    Log.v("Chalisa service", "on destroy called");*/
}//onDestroy

private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playerFlag = 0;
            }//if
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playerFlag = 0;
            }//if
            break;

            /**
             * Nitish 
             * 26 Sep 2012, Wed 
             * 11:50 AM*/
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                playerFlag = 1;
            }//if
        default:
            Log.d("Chalisa Service", "Unknown phone state=" + state);
        }
    } 
};

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    playerFlag = 0;
    stopSelf();
    updateUI();
    Log.v("Chalisa Service media player", "on completion listener called");
}

private void updateUI() 
{
    Intent in = new Intent("com.dzo.HanumanChalisaWithAudioAndAlarm.UPDATE_UI");
    in.putExtra("Player_FLAG_VALUE", playerFlag);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(in);
}
}//ChalisaService
```

Comment: I think TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE is called unexpectedly !!!

Comment: But if I don't use  TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE music won't resume after call disconnection

Comment: Yuo can put a log there to see if I am correct..then i ll find out why it is called unexpectedly..!!

Comment: I think this is the reason :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549505/why-oncallstatechanged-on-android-is-invoked-more-than-one-time-in-a-single-ca

Comment: I had checked with TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE. If I don't put condition in that case, music won't resume.

Comment: I was suggesting something like this:http://pastie.org/4855422

Comment: So that v can know that the problem is with TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE !!

Comment: You are right, .CALL_STATE_IDLE has been called uneventually, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Try using a BroadcastReceiver instead of Service...I think it might be the problem cause Service runs continuously in background while Receiver doesnt !!!

Comment: Reply if that works for you !!

Comment: Also try this:http://pastie.org/4859247..as I have serious doubt in it !!

Comment: How are you starting your service: STICKY or NON_STICKY?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sorry, I forgot to update. I had solved the issue. And the service is NON_STICKY. Thanks for your concern.